# Minimize function with Scipy minimize

Tags: python, scipy

Trying to obtain the d value (integer) for which the Std_Diff objective function is minimal, using Scipy minimize.

My code:

```
def Std_Diff(d):
    return std(diff(df['BN'].values,d));

from scipy.optimize import minimize
b=(3,)
res = minimize(Std_Diff,(1,), method='SLSQP', bounds = b)

The **df['BN'].values** are 
Out[72]: 
array([ 2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  2,  7,  5,  7, 11,  8,  2, 11,  7, 15,  8,  7,
       12, 21, 19, 32, 35, 40, 35, 21, 19, 25, 20, 40, 80, 99], dtype=int64)
```

Error is

> IndexError: too many indices for array

In case I do not use `bounds`:

```
res = minimize(Std_Diff,(1,), method='SLSQP')
```

I get another error:

```
> in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter,
> ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, **unknown_options)
>     368                 fx = float(np.asarray(func(x)))
>     369             except:
> --> 370                 raise ValueError("Objective function must return a scalar")
>     371             # Compute the constraints
>     372             if cons['eq']: ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar.
```

Answer (score 2):

(I was stumbling around at the start, but I'll leave here so you can get some ideas of how to debug.)

---

You invoke `minimize` with:

```
Std_Diff,(1,)
```

that is the initial values is a scalar (or 1 number).  `minimize` takes it's clue from that and sets the search variable to the same.  That's the `d` it passes to your function, `Std_Diff`.  But it also expects that function to return a single value as well.  In other words, minimize a scalar function of a scalar value.

So `std(diff(df['BN'].values,1))` should return a scalar.  Evidently it does not.

---

OK, testing with the supposed `values`

```
In [115]: bf
Out[115]: 
array([ 2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  2,  7,  5,  7, 11,  8,  2, 11,  7, 15,  8,  7,
       12, 21, 19, 32, 35, 40, 35, 21, 19, 25, 20, 40, 80, 99], dtype=int64)
In [116]: np.std(np.diff(bf,1))
Out[116]: 9.9219733700285424
```

So my first guess is wrong.

---

Looking more carefully at the error stack, I see that the error occurs in your function, not after.  It looks like a problem with the use of `d`.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in diff(a, n, axis)
   1913         raise ValueError(
-> 1914             "order must be non-negative but got " + repr(n))
   1915     a = asanyarray(a)

ValueError: order must be non-negative but got array([-64259548.28233695])
```

In the unbounded case, the search variable can go negative (very much so), raising an error in `np.diff`.

(the error you show is from `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`.  It's not the primary error, but a secondary one.)

---

The problem when specifying bounds, is that specification is incomplete.  It requires a (min,max) tuple for each variable.  So this works:

```
In [147]: minimize(Std_Diff,1, method='SLSQP', bounds=((3,None),))
...
Out[147]: 
     fun: 9.921973370028542
     jac: array([ 64259549.28233695])
 message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
    nfev: 3
     nit: 5
    njev: 1
  status: 8
 success: False
       x: array([ 1.])
```

> Bounds for variables (only for L-BFGS-B, TNC and SLSQP).
>       `(min, max)` pairs for each element in `x`, defining
>       the bounds on that parameter. Use None for one of `min` or
>       `max` when there is no bound in that direction.

Look at the error line:

```
--> 341         bnderr = bnds[:, 0] > bnds[:, 1]
```

it expects `bnds` to be a 2d array with 2 columns.  For example:

```
In [153]: np.array(((3,10),))
Out[153]: array([[ 3, 10]])
In [154]: np.array((3,))
Out[154]: array([3])
```

---

I also modified the function to have a clearer idea of how its values changed

```
def Std_Diff(d):
    print(d)
    r = np.std(np.diff(bf,d))
    print(r)
    return r
```